# MBProgressHUD view not hiding

Tags: iphone, ios, mbprogresshud, hud

In one stack I am displaying the `MBProgressHUD` and if by using the other stack when some calculation called I want `MBProgressHUD` to remove from the view but it is not been removed from the hud ..check what mistake I am doing..

first stack called **LoginViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];

     [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES]; 
}

-(void)myTask {
    // Do something usefull in here instead of sleeping ...

    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

    [self.hud hide:YES];
    self.hud=nil;
    [self.hud removeFromSuperview];

    //[self.hud showWhileExecuting:@selector(myTask1) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
 }
```

now the`ViewController` get calls but view will be same Previous  and

after some calculation and I want that in  `ViewController` I want to remove the`HUD`  from the view by calling the method in the `LoginViewController`..check code

```
 - (void)didReceiveResponseFromServer:(NSString *)responseData
 {
     login=[[LoginViewController alloc]init];

     [self.login myTask];
 }
```

Comment: can you please elabarote., where you exactly want to hide your HUD layer?

Answer (score 1):

Set UP `MBProgressHUD`

```
- (void) setupHUD
{
    //setup progress hud
    self.HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds];
    [self.SpurView addSubview:self.HUD]; // add it as here.
    self.HUD.dimBackground = YES;
    self.HUD.minSize = CGSizeMake(150.f, 150.f);
    self.HUD.delegate = self;
    self.HUD.labelText = @"Loading...";
}
```

Then use for hide `[self.HUD hide:YES];`  as describe in your code .

Answer (score 0):

like me , 
I tyr `[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:bAnimatedView animated:YES]`
but it will no work at times when I quick push in and back out .
So I add something to check the view of MBProgressHUD.

```
 MBProgressHUD *HUD = [MBProgressHUD HUDForView:bAnimatedView];
 if (HUD!= nil) {
     [HUD removeFromSuperview];
     HUD=nil;
 }
```